# Get the AST from a C/C++ code without compiling from a Python application

Tags: python, c++, abstract-syntax-tree

I have been reading [this article (described here)](https://www.usenix.org/conference/usenixsecurity15/technical-sessions/presentation/caliskan-islam) and working on my own implementation of this. In the article they use an abstract syntax tree and a few other features to create a deep learning model for source code attribution.

Is it possible to get the abstract syntax tree of a c or c++ application from a Python application?

My research seems to show that this cannot be reliably done unless you can compile the code. Is there a way to get portions of it using a python script?

Comment: Only if you implement a complete C++ compiler in Python itself.

Comment: Really? wow. So my options are to implement a C++ compiler (i suppose I just need the parse part... but something I have no idea how to do) or just make a system call to a C++ compiler (knowing that most of the code sources are *nix and I'm on a windows machine)? Bummer.

Comment: C++ is the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today. Do you really think that anything except a real C++ compiler can correctly interpret everything that C++ consists of: classes, multiple inheritance, templates, operator overloading, etc? Templates isn't even real code to start with.

Comment: A classic example of Sam's point is Visual Studio's Intellisense assistance tool. It does it's best to help you spot mistakes as you make them and it's success rate is pretty good, but there are false positives and false negatives, and sometimes they are quite annoying, false positives refusing to go away even though the compiler proved them to be bogus. This is a tool that has had Zounds... hours of human effort and money invested in it over decades and still has to find a balance between correct and fast enough.

Comment: About 20 years ago I was tasked with doing similar in Java. I would have KILLED for the tools in [clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) at the time. I would have wrapped clang in Java and gotten on with the important part of the job: Interpreting the AST to derive the intent of the code (good luck with that last part).

Comment: Maybe a better question is are there analytical tools available that could give some idea on the complexity of the code without having to compile it. Further with any of those be able to be called from Python. I apologize if my question seems ignorant, but I'm not a c guy I'm a python guy.

Comment: Writing your own C++ compiler would be insane. Luckily Clang exists and has Python bindings. Eli Bendersky’s blog post on the topic could be a good starting point: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/07/03/parsing-c-in-python-with-clang

Comment: I do have that old "dragon" compiler book on my shelf... but perhaps another time. I found a tool that gives me some of the info I need without the AST. It is called "lizard." I may add it as an alternative answer but it doesn't answer the question I actually asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ you need to actually compile a snippet to get its AST.

You could guesswork from a snippet, but it would offer no guarantee. The reason for this is that code from elsewhere (headers, previous code) might affect the meaning of any piece of code.

Consider:

```
int x = y + z;
```

What do you expect the AST to be ? An addition and an assignment operator.

Now, what if z is `Foo z;`

```
class Foo
{
   operator int() { /* bunch of operations,*/ return 0;}
}
```

Suddenly, your AST contains more stuff.

Then you can also have:

```
#define z (y * y)
```

Again, your AST changes.

So, to get it correct, your need the whole thing, parsing the whole source, includes, running pre-processor, resolving templates, visibility, overloads.

In practice, people then use something like LLVM and pass the responsibility to an actual compiler.

Comment: But even using LLVM it's a signifcant effort to get something off the ground if you never used LLVM before.